# How to enable the HSQLDB Manager Tools menu since it's disabled

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb

I've just downloaded hsqldb version 2.2.28 and I want to **convert a mysql database to a hsqldb**. I read in some discussions forum that I should use the **manager tools menu**, however it's disabled everytime I start the hsqldb manager window.

Somepeople told me I have to download the **hsqldb utilites package** from the website, but there isn't any utility on sourceforge.

I haven't found anything on discussion forums or hsqldb official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build this tool yourself. It is easy to builds with the Gradle build script in the /build directory of the hsqldb zip. The transfer tool is a few years old, with some recent updates.

Alternatively, use a tool such as http://www.razorsql.com/ to convert the database. This may be the better option.